# setError does not clear after enter text in edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

`EditText setError` message does not clear, when I enter text in edittext in device. But its working in emulator.

I used below code in edittext xml code:
**`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`**

Please any one help me.

Comment: Use setError(null) when EditText text clear.

Comment: i already used seterror(null) code.it works in emulator,not in device.why??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

set **`TextWatcher`** to you `edittext`, and set **`setError(null)`** in `afterTextChanged` method.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                       

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        edittext.setError(null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works fine, but I didn't like it. That is too long... :-/

Answer (score 0):

Check value on Text Watcher and set or unset error on after value changed :

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         if (s.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
               edittext.setError(null);
         } else {
               edittext.setError("Value required");
         }
    }
});
```